# Comparing distributions from a factorial design

Tags: experiment-design, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, nested-data, fractional-factorial

I have the following experimental design: I have six animals, where three received treatment and the other three were used as control (so treatment and control animals are not paired). From each of the six animals I took a tissue sample and then looked at cells from that tissue sample under the microscope and counted the number of certain particles with the each cell. So per animal I have these counts for ~200 cells (the number of cells isn't identical between animals). I also measured the area of each cell as the area of the cells varies and the number of particles is correlated with cell area.

I want to compare whether the distributions of the particle counts differ between the treatment and control animals. I would like to avoid comparing moments of these count distributions (i.e., mean/variance/skewness/etc' using various linear or generalized linear models) and thus am looking for a KS-test based approach or perhaps a Kullback-Leibler divergence approach (although the latter gives the KL divergence rather than a p-value and for my case this is less interpretative).

The two trivial options I can immediately think of are:

1. Pool the particle counts from all animals in each condition and simply run a two-sample KS-test between these pooled data.
2. Perform all possible pairwise KS-test between all pairs of animals from the two conditions and adjust the p-values for multiple testing or so.

My question is whether there's a version of a KS-test (or any other similar test for comparing distributions) that deals with the fact that two distributions are to be compared and there are several samples for each distribution. In the case of my experiment this is called biological variability.

Comment: Can you state the specific factorial design you used, which variables, etc, with formulas? The question is unclear.

Comment: Is it clearer now?

Comment: If you are still interested in this Q, could you post the data?